# How to access parts of a list in R

Tags: r

I've got the optim function in r returning a list of stuff like this:

```
[[354]]
    r     k sigma 
389.4 354.0 354.0
```

but when I try accessing say list$sigma it doesn't exist returning NULL.

I've tried attach and I've tried names, and I've tried assigning it to a matrix, but none of these things would work
Anyone got any idea how I can access the lowest or highest value for sigma r or k in my list??

Many thanks!!

str gives me this output:

```
List of 354
 $ : Named num [1:3] -55.25 2.99 119.37
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "r" "k" "sigma"
 $ : Named num [1:3] -53.91 4.21 119.71
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "r" "k" "sigma"
 $ : Named num [1:3] -41.7 14.6 119.2
```

So I've got a double within a list within a list (?) I'm still mystified as to how I can cycle through the list and pick one out meeting my conditions without writing a function from scratch

Comment: First access list element, then sigma. `object[[354]]$sigma`.

Comment: Is there any command in R apart from typeof that can tell me the makeup of something?

Comment: @user1987097 [you might like #069](http://www.twotorials.com/) :)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: I think `$sigma` won't work, because it looks like element `[[354]]` is a named vector, not a list

Comment: @user1987097, yes, `str`.  Please see below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The key issue is that you have a list of lists** (or a list of data.frames, which in fact is also a list).
To confirm this, take a look at `is(list[[354]])`.

The solution is simply to add an additional level of indexing.  Below you have multiple alternatives of how to accomplish this.

---

you can use a vector as an index to `[[`, so for example if you want to access the third element from the 354th element, you can use

```
 myList[[ c(354, 3) ]]
```

---

You can also use character indecies, however, all nested levels must have named indecies.

```
names(myList) <- as.character(1:length(myList))
myList[[ c("5", "sigma") ]]
```

---

*Lastly, please try to avoid using names like `list`, `data`, `df` etc.  This will lead to crashing code and erors which will seem unexplainable and mysterious until one realizes that they've tried to subset a function*

---

### Edit:

In response to your question in the comments above:  If you want to see the structure of an object (ie the "makeup" of the object), use `str`

```
> str(myList)
List of 5
 $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ a    : num 0.654
  ..$ b    : num -0.0823
  ..$ sigma: num -31
 $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ a    : num -0.656
  ..$ b    : num -0.167
  ..$ sigma: num -49
 $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ a    : num 0.154
  ..$ b    : num 0.522
  ..$ sigma: num -89
 $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ a    : num 0.676
  ..$ b    : num 0.595
  ..$ sigma: num 145
 $ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ a    : num -0.75
  ..$ b    : num 0.772
  ..$ sigma: num 6
```

Comment: I was only using list as an example

Answer (score 1):

If you want -for example- all the sigmas, you can use sapply:

```
sapply(list, function(x)x["sigma"])
```

You can use that to find the minimum and maximum:

```
range(sapply(list, function(x)x["sigma"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using , `do.call` you can do this :

```
 do.call('[',mylist,354)['sigma']
```